# Error php70u-common confilict with php-common-5.4.x.... while installing php-mbstring

Tags: php, linux, redhat, phabricator, mbstring

I know that there are lot of topics like this but those solutions doesn't work for me.

I'm installing Phabricator on Oracle Linux. Everything works fine but when I try to open phabricator in browser (http://ip adress ) I receive a message:

> Missing Required Extensions Required PHP extensions are not installed.
>
> Install this PHP extension:
>
> mbstring

php-mbstring wasn't avalible so I found this repo and tried to install it. Here is what I receive:

```
yum install php-mbstring
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     |  26 kB     00:00
ius                                                      | 2.2 kB     00:00
mysql-connectors-community                               | 2.5 kB     00:00
mysql-tools-community                                    | 2.5 kB     00:00
mysql56-community                                        | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_UEKR3                                                | 1.2 kB     00:00
ol7_latest                                               | 1.4 kB     00:00
(1/2): ol7_latest/x86_64/updateinfo                        | 866 kB   00:00
(2/2): ol7_latest/x86_64/primary                           |  18 MB   00:03
ol7_latest                                                          14996/14996
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70u-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.0.9-1.ius.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.9-1.ius.el7 for package: php70u-mbstring-7.0.9-1.ius.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70u-common.x86_64 0:7.0.9-1.ius.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70u-common-7.0.9-1.ius.el7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried also with `--skip-broken` and nothing.

Generally, I have 3 extensions of mbstring:

```
php55u-mbstring.x86_64                   5.5.38-1.ius.el7                    ius
php56u-mbstring.x86_64                   5.6.24-1.ius.el7                    ius
php70u-mbstring.x86_64                   7.0.9-1.ius.el7                     ius
```

I tried to instal all of these by: `yum instal php55u-mbstring.x86_64` (for example), but there conflicts each time

**SOLVED**

The solution was very simple. I finally found php-mbstring version which fit to the version of my php and while installing, there were no conflits.

Comment: Which additional repo did you use?

Comment: @tricasse I updated my question

Comment: For me it worked with: `sudo yum install php70u-mbstring`